# Java Code to Schedule a SQL file to execute on specific date and time on UNIX machine

Tags: java

I am new to java, and looking for assistance to write a code in java which takes abc.sql file from local machine and execute it on specific date and time on unix server under given data space.

Comment: Why Java? It would be simpler to schedule a cron job which calls the command-line mysql executable, telling it to execute the SQL in the file.

Comment: @SamBarnum: Why do you assume MySQL is the rdbms? (I bet you're right, actually, but there is no mention of MySQL in the question).

Comment: Maybe he has a software requirement that needs control over the execution from the Java app. Using Java he could move the app from one point to another without need to know how to use the scheduler from the other system.

Comment: David, Asaph and Sam.. Thanks for your responses.... Actually cron job does not solves the purpose, I want to run the sql file on specific date and time.. I hope this time it would be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use Quartz as the library. If you know how to use webapps in Java there´s a Servlet within Quartz that start and stop the lib factory automaticaly for you.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Examples:
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks David, I will get back to you if want to know more on quartz-scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cron utility. You *should* read the man pages on it by executing

```
man cron
```

But if you're lazy (like me) and don't like reading man pages (like me), you could just Google this and find some good tutorials, like

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

In the cron job you make, set the command to run the Java file, just as you would type it in the Terminal to execute it normally.